# Finding the matrix of an interesting transformation

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

My graduate student instructor for my linear algebra class provided this problem that piqued my interest:

Let $V$ be the vector space of ${2 \times 2}$ matrices. Let $T$ be an operator on $V$ such that ${T(A) = CA^T}$ , note that $C$ is given by ,\begin{bmatrix}2&-1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}
Find $M(T)$, that is, the matrix of the transformation.
I've looked at the problem for a while and I can't quite figure it out, anybody wanna give it a shot and talk me through it?

Comment: Find the action on a basis for $V$.

Comment: Before talking about the matrix representation of a linear operator, one needs to choose a basis first. The matrix will depend on the chosen basis. There isn't a unique answer.

Comment: He said the matrix would be a 4 by 4 but is that true? Because then the matrix multiplication would not make any sense

Comment: @user1551 won't we take standard basis if not stated?

Comment: @CarsonNewman yes matrix will be $4 \times 4$ matrix. $T:V \to W   $ is linear transformation with $  dim(V)=m , dim(W)=n$ than corresponding matrix will be $n \times m$. Here dimension of domain is 4 and that of co domain is also 4.

Comment: @CarsonNewman here$ T: M_{2 \times 2}(R) \to M_{2 \times 2}(R) $. Do you agree this is true?

Comment: @CarsonNewman here i assumed field is of Real Numbers, other wise transformation matrix will be different if field is something like $Z_2, \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3369097/matrix-of-a-transformation-in-m-2-bbb-r-space

Comment: This might help you :)

Comment: @CarsonNewman I am not sure if you have been taught what the standard basis of $\mathbb F^{2\times2}$ is. E.g. in the answer provided by saurabh rana below, the ordered basis he/she uses is (in his/her symbols) $\{e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4\}$, but in linear algebra literature, *the* standard basis of $\mathbb F^{2\times2}$ is actually $\{e_1,e_3,e_2,e_4\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let {$e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4$} is basis of $M_{2 \times2}(R)$, namely

$$ \left[
\begin{matrix}
1&0\\
0&0\\
\end{matrix}
\right],\left[
\begin{matrix}
0&1\\
0&0\\
\end{matrix}
\right],\left[
\begin{matrix}
0&0\\
1&0\\
\end{matrix}
\right],\left[
\begin{matrix}
0&0\\
0&1\\
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

now $T(e_1)=Ce_1^T=Ce_1$ since $e_1$ transpose is $e_1$ itself.

$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
2&-1\\
0&1\\
\end{matrix}
\right]
\left[
\begin{matrix}
1&0\\
0&0\\
\end{matrix}
\right] =\left[
\begin{matrix}
2&0\\
0&0\\
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

now write it in basis of $$M_{2 \times 2 }(R)$$ which will give you first column of Matrix which will be $4 \times 4 $ matrix.

Proceed similarly for $e_2,e_3,e_4$.

Comment: so then the matrix would be: $$
\begin{matrix}
2 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2 & -1\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{matrix}
$$